# Exposing API Documentation Using Flask and Swagger

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I have build a small service with `flask` and already wrote a swagger yaml file to describe it's API. How can I expose the swagger file through the flask app?

I didn't mean to expose the file itself (`send_from_directory`) but to create new endpoint that will show it as swagger-ui (interactive, if possible)

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is what I did.

I used `flasgger` to and wrap my app with `flasgger.Swagger`. than I added 2 endpoints:

1. `/_api` serves the YAML file (with `send_from_directory`)
2. `/api` redirects to the flasgger api `/apidocs/index.html?url=/api` I'm sure it can be done better, but I
   failed to find it.

github: https://github.com/eplaut/python-butler/blob/master/butler/butler.py#L119

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flasgger, a Flask extension that wraps Swagger UI for Flask http://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of doing it:

- via Restful-Api (Api.doc)
- via getting swagger templates
- via registering blueprints (from flask-swagger-ui or smth).